# How to re-order Relationship segues in UITabBarController in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8

## Setup

- Xcode 8.3.3
- iOS 10

## Issue

Once a UITabBarController's segue is linked to a view, it seems the only way to change order (which defines the tab button order) is to delete the segue and create again. How to re-order without deleting?

eg:

[image: Storyboard eg.]

In this case, I want to move the segue to "Settings" at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the alternate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14564388/1736679) was the only way without deleting:

- Edit the xml and change the order of the `segue` tags under the `collections` tag for the `tabBarController`